# Need help in finding exception "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception:"

Tags: java, jaxb

I tried to store a resume in an online CRM on trying to save that i got the following exception

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException:
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[73,12]
>   Message: Character reference "&#x18"
>   is an invalid XML character.]

i can store the resumes using the apis which they have exposed .The Resume which i am sending is in simple text format

Comment: elaborate. What is the "resume" format, do you have access to the CRM code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#x18` is a representation of the character with hex value `18`, and this is not a character permitted by the XML specification (it's an ASCII control code of some form). JAXB is quite rightly refusing to parse it.

You need to find out what is writing that data in the first place, and fix it, because it's not writing valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

&#x18 [appears to be the CANCEL character](http://www.zvon.org/other/charSearch/PHP/search.php/search.php?request=18&searchType=3) . Is there some way the keyboard signal to stop the program could be ended up being read in to the input on resumption?